# How to translate a non-recreational but activism/protest "campout"?

Tags: translation, terminology

How to translate an activist **campout** (as in a protest site where people also camp)?

The full sentence I would like to translate (it would be great if you could help me out):

> The activists feared that the police would destroy their **campout**
>   before the first anniversary of the inauguration of president 蔡英文 on
>   May the 20th.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 激進分子怕警詧在蔡英文五月二十日的總統就職一周年之前搗毀他們的露營抗議活動。

Comment: It's the first time that I see the character 詧. The dictionary says it's a variant of 察. Is it the standard form used in Taiwan? Thanks.

Comment: Dictionary in Taiwan (http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=W00000121715) also lists it as a variant of 察. @Huang